# Open Xcode project and set active file from terminal

Tags: xcode, bash, terminal

Opening an Xcode project from the terminal is easy:

`open Foo.xcodeproj/`

But that just opens the project and resumes its previous state using `UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate` - so it just opens to the last active file you were editing.

Is there a way to open an Xcode project ***and*** specify which file it should open to?

What I've tried:

1. Editing `.xcuserstate` - nightmare, don't do it.
2. Running `open Foo/Foo.xcodeproj/` then `open Foo/Sources/main.swift` which works *some of the time*, but not always. (If you just generated the project and do this, it'll open the project, then in a separate window it'll open the file.)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Interesting problem. The trouble comes when the project was last open on a file that takes a while to load, like a xib or storyboard. If that's the case, then while Xcode is busy loading the xib, if you ask it to open another project file, it opens the new file in a new window. If it's not busy loading in its existing window, it opens the new file in the existing window.  I've added this to my list of questions to ask at WWDC.

Comment: @robmayoff Your description is more accurate—if Xcode is still loading the first file while the second `open` is executed it will open the second file in a new window. Otherwise, it will open the second file in the existing editor. I'd really appreciate it if you could find an answer while at WWDC! `man open` shows that you can pass arguments to the application following `--args`. I'd ask if Xcode has any launch arguments for specifying an active file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Xcode engineer named Mike pointed me at the `loaded` property of Xcode's `workspace document` scripting class. By polling this, we can wait until Xcode has finished loading the project (including loading the editor pane) before asking it to open the file. This lets up reliably open the file in its project's window.

Here's the `xopen` script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

sourceFile="$1"
case "$sourceFile" in
    /*) ;;
    *) sourceFile="$PWD"/"$sourceFile" ;;
esac

projectDir="$sourceFile"
while [[ $projectDir = */* ]]; do
    projectDir="${projectDir%/*}"
    candidates=("$projectDir"/*.xcodeproj)
    candidate="${candidates[0]}"
    if [[ "$candidate" != "" ]]; then
    jPath="$candidate"
    fi
done

if [[ "$jPath" = "" ]]; then
    echo 1>&2 "error: couldn't find .xcodeproj in any parent directory"
    exit 1
fi

exec osascript - "$jPath" "$sourceFile" <<EOF
on run argv
    set jPath to item 1 of argv
    set sourceFile to item 2 of argv
    tell app "Xcode"
    set wsDoc to (open jPath)
    set waitCount to 0
    repeat until wsDoc's loaded or waitCount ≥ 20
        set waitCount to waitCount + 1
        delay 1
    end repeat
    if wsDoc's loaded then
        open sourceFile
    end if
    end tell
end run
EOF
```

This script uses the shell to walk up the directory tree from the source file (given as a command line argument) until it finds a directory containing an Xcode project package. Then it passes the path to the project and the path to the source file to an AppleScript. The AppleScript asks Xcode to open the project. If Xcode already has the project open, it'll just bring the existing project window to the front.

Next, the script polls Xcode until it reports that the workspace document is loaded, or until 20 seconds have elapsed.

Finally, if the workspace document is loaded, it asks Xcode to open the source file. Xcode will open the source file in the existing project window's editor.

Comment: Very nice! Thank you so much for leveraging WWDC to get this answer! Hats off to you and thanks.